# How can i create a toast when longpress anywhere in the view in android?

Tags: android, long-press

Hi I need to create a toast when we longpress anywhere in the view in the application.

My toast is:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Can anyone help me for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: on click of ur root layout u need to show toast.

Answer (score 1):

```
  myView = findViewById(r.id.my_view);
  myView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Clicked " ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;    // set to true
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats not fair for my application. I need to longpress in the current activity itself. I need to longpress in the view. If there is any other way for that???

Comment: just change button by yourViewOrLayout simple .

Answer (score 0):

Your class can use the interface onLongClickListener.

Your class extends Activity implements View.OnLongClickListener which has the method that get notified on long press.

**Don't forget to set yourView.setOnLongClickListener(this); for all the views you need.**

Answer (score 0):

for Example, if You have a top layout like a LinearLayout, set this on LongClick:

Your layout.xml

```
  <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/your_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
```

Your Activity.java

```
 LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_layout);

 yourLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
       public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(yourMainActivity.this, "Your Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return true;
     }

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

***To create a toast when longpress anywhere in the view in android -***

*LongPress VIEW* **===>**

[image]

---

*LongPress.java class -*

```
public class LongPress extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_long_press);
  TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
  txtView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "You have pressed it long :)", 2000).show();
    return true;
   }
  });
  txtView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Long Enough :(",
      1000).show();
   }
  });
 }

}
```

*Relevant layout file -*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".LongPress" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Long Press Me!!!!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Source: [android-long-press-event-handle-example](http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-long-press-event-handle-example.html).